# Return an Attribute Value to an Object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I`need to return the attribute value of "data-animate" and "data-speed" to the object fxBalloon. In that object those string values should be passed to **duration : $speedFX** and **name :$nameFX** but comes up undefined. Please look at code below and link for reference

https://codepen.io/paul-solomon/pen/MzjYmK?editors=1111.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="balloon">
          <div class="fxballoon" data-animate="b_layer1" data-speed="6s">
            <span>sample</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fxballoon" data-animate="b_layer2" data-speed="5s">
            <span>sample</span>
          </div>
           <div class="fxballoon" data-animate="b_layer3" data-speed="3s">
             <span>sample</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

//Global Var
var $elemClass = $(".balloon .fxballoon"); 

var fxBalloon = {
  elem : $elemClass,//Class or Id
  name :$nameFX,  //Sets Option Name for Balloon Animation 
  duration : $speedFX, //Sets Option for Speed  
  delay :  "ease-in-out", //Sets Option for Easing 
  count : "infinite", // sets an Infinite Loop
  action : "paused", // Sets the Play or Pause Action
  $nameFX: function() {
     dataAnimation();
    },
  $speedFX: function() {
    dataSpeedAnimation();
    },
  $animationFX: function() {
  $(this).each(function() { //Iterates over the object FxController    
 setAnimation(this.elem,this.name,this.duration,this.delay,this.count,this.action);
     });
    }
  };



fxBalloon.$animationFX();

 // loops to get the data-speed attribute value from DOM
 function dataSpeedAnimation(){
    for( var i = 0; i < $elemClass.length;i++){
     // console.log($elemClass[i].getAttribute("data-speed"));
      $elemClass[i].getAttribute("data-speed");
    }
  }
 // loops to get the data-animate attribute value from DOM
 function dataAnimation(){
      for( var i = 0; i <  $elemClass.length;i++){
        return $elemClass[i].getAttribute("data-animate");
      }
    }

// Object Construct for CSS to animate styles to DOM
function setAnimation(elem, name, duration, delay, count, action) {
$(elem).css({ "-webkit-animation": name + " "+ duration + " "+ delay + " "+ count });
$(elem).css({ "-moz-animation": name + " "+ duration + " "+ delay + " "+ count });
$(elem).css({ "-o-animation": name + " "+ duration + " "+ delay + " "+ count  });
$(elem).css({ "animation": name + " "+ duration + " "+ delay + " "+ count});
$(elem).css({ "animation-play-state:": action});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var fxBalloon = {
  elem : $elemClass,//Class or Id
  name :"ease-in-out",  //Sets Option Name for Balloon Animation 
  duration : "ease-in-out", //Sets Option for Speed  
  delay :  "ease-in-out", //Sets Option for Easing 
  count : "infinite", // sets an Infinite Loop
  action : "paused", // Sets the Play or Pause Action
  $nameFX: 
   dataAnimation(),
  $speedFX: 
     dataSpeedAnimation(),
  $animationFX: function() {

     $(this).each(function() { //Iterates over the object FxController
         dataSpeedAnimation(); 
 setAnimation(this.elem,this.name,this.duration,this.delay,this.count,this.action);
     });
    }
  };
 fxBalloon.$animationFX();
```

Comment: Is there any way get the values of html attributes data-animate and data-animate and apply them to the name and duration values in the object fxballoon, I have a for loop function that iterates to get attributes. I want to be able to control the duration at different speeds (eg: 6s.5s,4s) pulling from the data-speed function. same with name value in the Object(eg:b_layer1,b_layer2, b_layer3).

Comment: instead run a loop outside the object

Comment: I already have the loop outside of the object. the Object comes back undefined when I call it in the object.